# Problems in switching frames with tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm implementing a GUI with Tkinter following this topic: [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter)

Trying to adapting it to my problem:

This is the controller:

```
class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title('VOICED/UNVOICED SPEECH DETECTION')
        self.resizable(RESIZABLE, RESIZABLE)
        self.geometry(str(WIDTH_WINDOW) + 'x' + str(HEIGHT_WINDOW))
        self.configure(bg=BACK_GROUND_COLOR)
        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")
        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (HomePage, MenuPage, GraphicPage):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("HomePage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
```

This is the home page that shows the lateral bar:

[image]

And the corresponding code:

```
class HomePage(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    self.bg = BACK_GROUND_COLOR

    label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

    # -----------ROOT WINDOWS-------------

    self.configure(bg=BACK_GROUND_COLOR)
    self.position = 0

    # ----------Menu Bar-------------------------

    self.menu_frame = tk.Frame(master=self, height=HEIGHT_WINDOW, width=50,
                               borderwidth=5, relief='groove', highlightbackground="black",
                               highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, bg=BACK_GROUND_COLOR).place(x=0, y=0)
    # Menu Button
    self.menu_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='frontend/Widget/icons/menu.png')
    self.menu_button = tk.Button(master=self.menu_frame, image=self.menu_img,
                                 height=25, width=25,
                                 command=lambda: controller.show_frame("MenuPage"),
                                 bg=BACK_GROUND_COLOR).place(x=10, y=10)

    # Back Button
    self.back_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='frontend/Widget/icons/back.png')
    self.back_button = tk.Button(master=self.menu_frame, image=self.back_img, height=25, width=25,
                                 bg=BACK_GROUND_COLOR).place(x=10, y=46)

    # Home Button
    self.home_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='frontend/Widget/icons/home.png')
    self.home_button = tk.Button(master=self.menu_frame, image=self.home_img, height=25, width=25,
                                 bg=BACK_GROUND_COLOR).place(x=10, y=82)
```

When I click the menu button (the first in the lateral bar), I obtain the menu option (That I called MenuPage):

[image]

And the corresponding code:

```
    class MenuPage(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

            self.controller = controller
            self.bg = BACK_GROUND_COLOR

            # --------------------------------------------------toolbar--------------------------------------

            self.toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(master=self, height=70, width=WIDTH_WINDOW - 54,
                                          borderwidth=5, relief='groove', highlightbackground="black",
                                          highlightcolor="black",
                                          highlightthickness=1, bg=BACK_GROUND_COLOR).place(x=51, y=0)

            self.button_graphics_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='frontend/Widget/icons/graphic.png')
            self.button_graphic = tk.Button(master=self, text='Test/Train',
                                            image=self.button_graphics_img, height=25, width=25, bg=BACK_GROUND_COLOR,
                                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("GraphicPage")).place(x=75, y=5)

            self.label_graphic = tk.Label(master=self, text='Plot Parameters',
                                          height=0, width=12, bg=BACK_GROUND_COLOR).place(x=55, y=40)
```

As you can notice, when I click on the menu button the lateral frame disappears. This is because in the MenuPage there aren't the methods of the lateral bar, but trying to put it also in the MenuPage, the buttons (back arrow, home) don't work. 
So I don't get how  to hold fixed the lateral bar for all my pages and make sure that the buttons do their job.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

By placing the sidebar in the Main Windows, I solved the fact that the sidebar disappeared when I opened the menu.

The other problem is:

How can I do with the back arrow to come back to the previous Frame? For Instance, if I open another page with a button in the MenuPage, and then I'd want to come back to from that page to the MenuPage, how should I do? 
I've already tried to re-place the buttons in the page opened from menu changing the command to open the previous page (putting `lambda: controller.show_frame("MenuPage")` ) but doesn't works.

Comment: You need to put the Menu Page on your Main Window, it would be the app. then place your pages beside them.

Comment: Thank you, in this way I solved a part of my problem. Another problem is: How can I do with the back arrow to come back to the previous Frame? For Instance, if I open another page with a button in the MenuPage, and then I'd want to come back to from that page to the MenuPage, how should I do? I've already tried to re-place the buttons in the page opened from menu but doesn't works.

Comment: Not sure what happens in your program. You added the Buttons and the Frame of MenuPage to app ? Not the Class just the widgets right?

Comment: Your buttons stays now how intended while switching frames, right?

Comment: Maybe you need to configure the Buttons on HomePage and global the Buttons, so everything is known when you define the Buttons. But becareful, after you global a var you cant take the var for other widgets anymore or it will be messed up.

Comment: Yes I added the frame of the sidebar and the buttons (back, home, menu) also in the class that represent  the page opened, changing the command to   come back to previous frame.

Comment: Now, I re-tried and it seems works, but I hoped to find a better way to do it, because, in this way I have much duplicated code. In fact in each class I have to re-put the widget of the side-bar

Comment: Yes the buttons stays now how intended while switching frames

Comment: the app is your main window it should stay there all the time, normally you dont have to put the widgets again and again, except you place your pages over the menu. But I guess you need to config the buttons in your first page, cause all args are known there, so you need to global the buttons for configure them.

Comment: What do you mean global the buttons to configure them?

Comment: you can global your buttons, so they will be known everywhere in your code. You need to write a single line above global Name_of_Button to do it.